# Regular expression. Find three words in the field

Tags: javascript, regex

Help make the correct regular expression for the search 3 words into the field. So far I have done so, but I think it's crazy.

```js
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.onclick = function() {
  console.log(inp.value.match(/^([а-яa-z0-9]+ ){2}[а-яa-z0-9]+/i));
};
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve, please provide some examples, and explain a little better what is your problem

Comment: Try: `"abc cde cme".match(/[^\s]{3}/g)`

Comment: It is necessary to check whether it is a field just three words. No more no less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's easier to split the text and then verify that the element count is as you expect it. You may want to trim the text before to avoid leading and trailing empty strings in the result array.

```
console.log(inp.value.trim().split(/\s+/))
```